# How to export model from Oracle SQL Developer Modeler into E/R Studio Data Architect (Idera Embarcadero)

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

Is there a way to export a subject area from oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler to E/R Studio Data Architect?

Answer (score 0):

- Open ER/Studio Data Architect.
- Click File > New > Create a New Model> click on Import Model from > and choose “External Metadata” > Click “Import”
- Import External Metadata (page 1 of 3)> select ” Import From”  > choose -> Oracle Database SQL DDL.
- Under File, click the three dots ellipsis, and select the location where your Oracle DDl sql file was created, when you reverse engineered your model using  Oracle Data Modeler, and enter your default schema name.

Click “Next”  > “Next” and then “Finish”. Your Oracle Data Modeler Model is now imported into ER/Studio